# Structured distribution list in Outlook. Is it possible?

Tags: outlook, ldap

I have the following need...

Assume we have this structure of groups and email addresses

```
|-Group A
|--- Sub Group A
|----- User 1(email1)
|----- User 2(email2)
|--- Sub Group B 
|----- User 3(email3)
|------User 4(email4)
```

Is there a way to have Outlook merge these according to a selection of a group or multiple groups?

for example:

```
senario1: send email to GroupA -> Results in: email1, email2,email3,email4
senario2: send email to Sub Group B -> Results in: email3,email4
```

the whole thing seems like an LDAP implementation, 
but I'm not sure about the MS Outlook part.

Thanks in advance.